# Use count in Terraform with an offset

Tags: terraform

I want to create some resources with Terraform and include the count.index to them with an offset defined in the var.tf file, like:

vm-app-04

vm-app-05

vm-app-06

vm-app-04-nic-01

vm-app-05-nic-01

vm-app-06-nic-01

Whenever I try to add ${var.count_offset} I get either "Error: Invalid character" or "Error: Invalid expression". Is there a way how I can create this behaviour?

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count                     = "${var.nb_instances}"
  name                      = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}-nic-01"
  location                  = "${module.global_variables.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${module.global_variables.resource_group_name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig01"
    subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet_id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment}}"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record" {
  count               = "${var.nb_instances}"
  name                = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"
  zone_name           = "${module.global_variables.dns_zone}"
  resource_group_name = "${module.global_variables.resource_group_name}"
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.private_ip_address, count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"]
  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

This is the Output I get:

```
Error: Invalid character

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 72, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic":
  72:   name                      = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}-nic-01"

This character is not used within the language.


Error: Invalid expression

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 72, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic":
  72:   name                      = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}-nic-01"

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.


Error: Invalid character

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record":
 128:   name                = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"

This character is not used within the language.


Error: Missing argument separator

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record":
 128:   name                = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"

A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.


Error: Invalid character

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 132, in resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record":
 132:   records             = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.private_ip_address, count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"]

This character is not used within the language.


Error: Missing argument separator

  on ../../../modules/computation/cluster-module/vm.tf line 132, in resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record":
 132:   records             = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.private_ip_address, count.index + 1 + ${var.count_offset})}"]

A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.
```

Comment: Can you also include the code that errors? Right now you're just showing the code without the offset.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my post now

Comment: You don't need the `${}` around `var.count_offset`.

Comment: It solved the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be nesting the `${}` as this is just used to tell Terraform to interpolate the inside of it so you can drop the `${}` around `var.count_offset`.

With that change your code should just be:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count               = var.nb_instances
  name                = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + var.count_offset)}-nic-01"
  location            = module.global_variables.location
  resource_group_name = module.global_variables.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig01"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment}}"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "add_A_record" {
  count               = var.nb_instances
  name                = "${var.vm_hostname}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1 + var.count_offset)}"
  zone_name           = module.global_variables.dns_zone
  resource_group_name = module.global_variables.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.private_ip_address, count.index + 1 + var.count_offset)}"]
  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```